# How to handle XmlIDREF when you don't know the referenced element/class

Tags: jaxb

How do you handle references when you do not know what the referenced element type will be?

I have an element `<input>` which is a data sink. The element `<input>` has an attribute `source` which specifies (references by `XmlIDREF`) where the data comes from. The element referenced by `source` could be one of multiple elements.

Here is an example from a test document I am using, in which the `<input>`'s `source` sometimes references a `<source>` element and sometimes references a `<vertices>` (and those are not necessarily the only elements it could reference):

```
    <source id="position">
      <float_array id="arrayPosition" count="78">...</float_array>
      ...
    </source>
    <source id="normal">
      <float_array id="arrayNormal" count="144">...</float_array>
      ...
    </source>
    <vertices id="vertex">
      <input semantic="POSITION" source="position"/>
    </vertices>
    <polylist material="MyMaterial" count="40">
      <input semantic="VERTEX" source="vertex" offset="0"/>
      <input semantic="NORMAL" source="normal" offset="1"/>
      ...
    </polylist>
```

If I do

```
class Input
{
    Source source;
}
```

then all references to `<source>` elements work correctly, but for the rest of them their source is `null`. That is, if I were to set up a `toString()` to show the class and id and print the above inputs, I would get

```
Source: position
null
Source: normal
```

The first line would correctly reference the first `<source>` element, the second line, which I would want to reference the `<vertices>` element, would be `null`, and the third would reference the second `<source>` element.

If I were to change `Input` to have a field `Vertices source` instead, then I would get `null` `Vertices vertex` and `null` instead. This makes sense.

How would I structure my Java code to handle this?

I have looked into the XmlAdapter, thinking maybe I could give class `Input` a field `Object source` or `MySuperClass source` (and make both `Source` and `Vertices` subclasses of it) or `JAXBElement source` and then try to convert things in the adapter code, but how then would I preserve the id reference?

I looked into `XmlType` and factory usage, but that does not seem to be at all what I'm looking for, or at least I don't see how it applies, despite it sounding at first like a good candidate.

Googling for related terms produced all kinds of referencing problems other people had which were not related.

I'm thinking that, however it is done, one of two things will have to be true:
1) `Source` and `Vertices` (and everything else that `Input` can reference with its `source` field) will have to extend a common super class.
or
2) `Input` will have a `Source source1` and a `Vertices source2` (and so on, to `ClassN sourcen`), of which 1 of them will reference something and all the others will be null.

I'm fine with either of those two scenarios, and also to alternatives, as long as it unmarshalls all the data and preserves the references so I can get at all of the information. I just cannot figure out the proper way to have it unmarshalled.

I have no control over the xml that I get. The xml documents are created by other programs and the schema follows a large specification (http://www.khronos.org/files/collada_spec_1_4.pdf). I am only writing Java code necessary to unmarshal the xml and use the data from those files.

I just started using jaxb last night, and it works **great** (kudos again to the devs), but there are a few lingering things like this I still have to work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root**

Each object referenced by `@XmlIDREF` also needs to be reference through a nested relationship. They don't all need to be reference by the same class as in this example.

```java
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement(name="foo")
    private List<Foo> foos;

    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement(name="bar")
    private List<Foo> bars;

}
```

**Foo**

A property annotated with `@XmlIDREF` will match any element of any type no matter where it occurs in the document.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

    @XmlID
    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlAttribute
    private Object reference;

}
```

**Bar**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Bar {

    @XmlID
    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

}
```

**Demo**

```java
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum17799549/input.xml");
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <foos>
        <foo id="B" reference="C"/>
        <foo id="A" reference="B"/>
    </foos>
    <bars>
        <bar id="C"/>
    </bars>
</root>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html

Comment: That works. Also, if I do make Source and Vertices extend the same class, I can give Input a "ParentClass source" too. But I could have sworn I was trying this last night and getting an error stating that jaxb would not allow me to have my Java class extend another class. I'm not sure why it is letting me now. Apparently there are some nuances of jaxb that I have yet to sort out. Anyway, thank you for the answer, as it steered me back onto the correct path which I had previously abandoned before getting it to work. Now it's good!